# How to decide between regex and wildcard in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When we are trying to do a regex on around 10 different terms, we get the following exception:

```
ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=too_complex_to_determinize_exception, reason=too_complex_to_determinize_exception: Determinizing automaton with 67 states and 278 transitions would result in more than 10000 states.]];
```

Increasing the boost will resolve the error. But the number of terms passed will differ and cant fix a specific value. I am thinking of using wildcard.

Wildcard also internally creates states, so whether using wild card is a better approach or is there a better way?

My sample query using regex:

```
search {"from":0,"size":0,"timeout":"60s","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"regexp":{"filed_name":

{"value":".*term.*|.*term.*|.*term.*|.*term.*|.*term.*|.*term.*|.*term.*|.*term.*|.*term.*|.*term.*|.*term.*","flags_value":65535,"max_determinized_states":10000,"boost":1.0}

}},{"range":{"condition_field":

{"from":0,"to":null,"include_lower":false,"include_upper":true,"boost":1.0}

}},{"range":{"condition_filed":

{"from":0,"to":null,"include_lower":false,"include_upper":true,"boost":1.0}

}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0}},"profile":true,"sort":[{"_id":{"order":"asc"}}]}
```

Comment: If you can, it is better to design an analysis chain to produce _better_ terms on which to search, _better_ here meaning terms stored in the inverted index better align with the typical way in which the data is expected to be searched. `regexp` and `wildcard` queries are flexible but are usually slower and computationally expensive.

Comment: Actually, wildcard equivalent of the above query gives result without throwing any exception. In underlying architecture, both creates automaton states. Then why regex throws error while wild card fetches results. I am more interested to know the difference of these two, rather than the analysis.

Comment: Wildcard works but Regexp fails is likely because the number of determinized states  whilst creating and minimizing automata is much greater in the latter case. You can increase the maximum number of determinized states higher than 10,000 but it will increase the resources consumed both constructing the automaton and executing it.

Comment: For reference, here's the RegExp `toAutomaton` impl: https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/1cda4245032d1e0702f9c5e06bafcdfc22bdec60/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.java#L502-L608, and Wildcard impl: https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/1cda4245032d1e0702f9c5e06bafcdfc22bdec60/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/WildcardQuery.java#L75-L105

Comment: Thanks @RussCam, the references helps!